# Change text between tags in HTML document

Tags: html, vb.net

Basically I was wondering if anybody knows how to make Visual Basic change automatically what is in

```
<span id="total_quantity">1</span>
```

change what is between `>` and `<`  (for example a digit or text).

How can I do that?

Comment: You mean VB.NET (with ASP.NET) or vbscript (with ASP) or some other environment?

Comment: I’ve rewritten the post to be more readable. However, I *still* have no idea what exactly you want to achieve, and where your problem is. You need to provide way more details: How is the input provided? How does it look like? How does the output happen? What have you tried? Where have you got problems?

Comment: ok so i have <span id="total_quantity">1</span>, i want to change what ever is in the >and< in visual basic, so when ever a webpage loads it looks up the id which i know and changes the number or text between >and<

Comment: i also been Visual basic 2010 Express

Comment: It sounds like you want a server-side process to look up a product id in a database and put a value into that `<span>` element. But you haven't given any of that context.

Comment: what do i need to give, i just want to change whatever is in the >"<      meaning a number or a digit, where i have put the number 1 right now. if that make sense

Comment: Are you trying to change code that has already been rendered on the page?

Comment: um, basically it is a drop down box, which you can select on a web page and then it sends it to a textbox, it looks like this       http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/577/screenshot20120623at154.png/

Comment: i have this code which selects from the dropdown box                       If TextBox1.Text = ("weburl") Then
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("price_category").SetAttribute("value", "4")
End If                                                                  by i am trying to edit the textbox on the site because when the code selects it from the drop-down it doesn't change the text box this is what i am trying to do in vb

Comment: I recommend using javascript to do any modification on the page after it has been rendered.  Jquery has a few solutions for things like this.

http://api.jquery.com/change/
http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/

Comment: so, um what is this for changing the drop down or...

Answer (score 0):

If you have many tasks that involve manipulating HTML, I would recommend [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net)